# Mastermind Permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Recall that Mastermind codes consist of an ordered row of four colors. (For instance,
RED BLUE BLUE ORANGE is one code; BLUE RED BLUE ORANGE is a different
code.) There are six different colors to choose from. How many ways are there of
choosing a Mastermind code that uses the color orange exactly once?

Answer (score 1):

You can place the orange in any of $4$ slots.  Then the question becomes, how many distinct codes can be formed from five colors in the remaining three slots; the answer is obviously $5^3$.  So the answer to your question is $500$.